# sort values in pyspark > Does it give good and reliable results?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, dask

I am new with pyspark.

I need to analyze big CSV files .
at the beginning of the analyze I had to sort the data by ID  and TIME .

I tried to use dask in order to do it but I realize that it give wrong answer and also many times it  stuck in the middle. So  dask **not good** with sorting values as mentioned in the link . apparently Because it do in parallel way.

https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.sort_values.html

My question is how pyspark handle with this issue?
Does it give good and  reliable   results?

If the answer is yes I would like to know how spark is sorting data   in parallel way and why it is difficult to dask

Comment: I don't think the intention in the dask docs is to suggest that dask is particularly worse in comparison to other general purpose distributed computing options. Instead, it's a warning that in general, sorting larger-than-memory datasets in a distributed cluster is very expensive in terms of computation, I/O, network, memory, etc.

Comment: Do you think you could make your question a bit more focused? Right now I'm not sure what you're asking - is it "how to implement an efficient sort in pyspark?" or "... in dask?" or "how does spark implement sorts under the hood"? or "why does dask have a hard time with distributed sort?" all of these would have very different answers and may or may not be suitable questions for stack overflow vs. a discussion on a forum specific to one of these communities (e.g. dask's gitter channel). See [ask].

Comment: thansk michael. I edited the question

Comment: Sorry this still doesn’t work. Check out the guide to [ask]. You need to ask one targeted question. If you’re running into trouble with dask, please feel free to show us your code and ask for dask help. If dask is giving incorrect answers that will be taken seriously and we’ll try to help. But we can’t just explain all the differences between two different programming frameworks.

Comment: If you’re asking about how to do something in pyspark, then show your pyspark code and ask a specific pyspark question, but don’t mention dask.